Convergence of moments implies convergence of the measure in the space of tempered distributions?
Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the Schwartz space and $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the space of tempered distributions.
Denote by $\{\mu_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ a sequence of Borel probability measures on $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
For any $\omega \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, denote by $\omega^{\otimes n}$ the $n$-fold tensor product of $\omega$, which is a well-defined element of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{nd})$ by the nuclear theorem.
Suppose that there exists a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{k \to \infty }\int_{\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)}\omega^{\otimes n}(f) d\mu_k(\omega) = \int_{\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)} \omega^{\otimes n}(f) d\mu(\omega)
\end{equation}
for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{nd})$.
Then, my question is

In what sense does $\{\mu_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ converge to $\mu$ precisely?

This is obviously convergence of moments in tempered distibution sense...Could anyone please help me?
